Why does console.time/performance.measure and memory inspector don't have similar values
I'm trying to make an application that measures the times of loops with different data
This is example for memory inspector vs console.time:


Any advice or criticism is welcome from how to improve the code to measure time more precisely to improving other aspects of the code.

It is also possible to modify the code of yourself on github.
Code:https://github.com/KovacevicAleksa
